# Django migrations are not migrating at all

Tags: python, django, migration

```
class Charity(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=True)
        pictureurl = models.URLField(max_length=500, null=True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField(CharityTag)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.name}, {self.pictureurl},{self.description}, {self.tags}"
    
class Donor(models.Model):
        first = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        last = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        recc = models.ForeignKey(Charity, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        frequency = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.first}, {self.last}, {self.recc}, {self.frequency}"
```

So I have made a couple of models like these. I did python manage.py makemigrations and all i get is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'donationss'`

I am CD into the Startproject directory, not the Startapp one

In the settings in Installed_Apps i put `'donationss.apps.DonationssConfig'`,

I have upgraded pip and django and the migrates still don't happen. Never had this issue.

Comment: Do you have a typo in `donationss` with that last extra `s` ?

Comment: No, the migrations are not even happening, no new instance with the new database gets added. 
All I have done is start a project - start an app - create the models - and attempt to migrate them - register them for the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error , but in my case I had missed a comma (`,`) in `INSTALLED_APPS.`